# convert numbers to strings in groovy

Tags: java, groovy

Is there any way to convert numbers to strings in pure Groovy OR concatenate a number and a string to a string. It *almost* seems like you can.

For example:

```
def t = [:]
t['a' << 24] = "happy"
println t
println t.get('a24')
```

Line 3 will display something like `[a24:happy]` but it will not be retrievable in line 4. Changing the 2nd line to `t['a24'] = "happy"` displays seemingly the same print on line 3 but it actually fetches the result in the 4th line.

If I check the types on each, they both return `class java.util.LinkedHashMap`

So, again, is there a pure Groovy way of converting a number into a string and/or combining string + number or must it be done in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy implements `<<` by calling `leftShift()`, so `'a' << 24` actually calls [`String.leftShift(Object value)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#leftShift(java.lang.Object)), which returns a `StringBuffer`, not a `String`.

That means that your map key is a `StringBuffer`, so calling `get('a24')`, where you pass in a `String`, will not find anything.

You can see that by printing the type:

```
t.each { k, v -> println k.getClass() } // prints: class java.lang.StringBuffer
```

Comment: Makes sense.  In my above example using `t['a' + 24]` works then. I'm not sure why I got off on using `<<` but nevertheless. Thanks for the clarification.